# Batter up! (A cryptic clue)

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

Big noise in dugout retired by Rutherford? (4, 7)

> A hint will cost you NZ$100!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> PLUM PUDDING

because

> the "plum pudding" model of the atom (an extended positive blob with small electrons spread about in it like raisins in a plum pudding) was made obsolete ("retired") by Ernest Rutherford's experiments shooting alpha particles at gold foil

and

> one can parse it as PLUMP (big) + DIN (noise) inside UDG (dugout = DUG out = anagram of DUG).

Incidentally,

> I think it's actually the $100 note.

I think the title

> is deliberate misdirection, because for some readers the most notable New Zealander called Rutherford might be [this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Rutherford_(cricketer)) or even his son Hamish, both of whom are *batsmen*.

Comment: How embarrassing, I have a 50 in my wallet, too.

Comment: Any comment on the title?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant to say something about that. Will edit. [Now done. Not sure there isn't some further thing that I'm missing, though.]

Comment: More to do with multiple meanings of "batter"

Comment: I wouldn't have thought uncooked plum pudding stuff would be called "batter", if that's what you mean: wrong sort of consistency.

Comment: https://food-mag.co.uk/plum-pudding-recipe/ says it's a batter.